# How to monitor a specific site with Google Alert

Tags: google-alerts

I want to use Google Alerts to search for a specific site with several interesting links:

```
site: mysite.com
```

However, I just want to monitor **this** site and no other sites and get the links which change on this site when they change.

Is this possible with Google?

Answer (score 5):

I tried this with a website yesterday and it actually worked as expected using the query style you have there: `site:mysite.com`. It has yet to bring up any links from outside the site.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible with Google Alerts, but there are a number of other products that do exactly what you're looking for.  I used https://www.followthatpage.com/ and I'm pretty happy with it so far.

Comment: It's too bad it can't render Javascript.

Comment: Follow that page threw an error when I tried signing up. I signed up at https://visualping.io/ for daily updates which are free. It has paid plans for more frequent updates.